# SQL Manager: How to move favorite queries to another database

Tags: postgresql, sql-manager

I use SQL Manager with PostgreSQL 9.3.18, and I have to restore the main database, located on server, to a new local DB every week. Ending up with 4 databases the last week of each month. 
I have a bunch of favorite queries that I need them in all restored in the local databases. Each time that I make a restored DB, I have to create the favorite queries one by one. 
Is there any way to move them to another database easily.

[image]

Comment: What is a favorite query in a database? Is that a feature of some client application?

Comment: No, in SQL Manager for PostgreSQL if you connect to a DB and scroll down you see the fav. queries. I'll add an image to show that.

Comment: That was the missing information! Your question is not about PostgreSQL at all. I have edited it to clarify that.